# How to get last tmux lines?

Tags: linux, bash, script, tmux

I'm writting a script that's suppossed to open *x* number of tmux sessions, check for the last line and then, deppending on the output, do this or that, but I just can not find a way of saving tmux's output.

So far I tried redirecting the output normally `>` and also using the `capture-pane` option like this: `tmux capture-pane -t session1 > file` but I get nothing inside the file.

I was considering using expect if needed but a bash solution would be much greater.

Answer (score 4):

The capture-pane saves the data to a buffer.  The ">" saves stdout to a file.  A buffer and stdout are not necessarily the same thing.  You'll need the tmux command "save-buffer" to work.  Something like the following.

```
tmux capture-pane -S -10 ; save-buffer 'file' ; delete-buffer
```

The `capture-pane -S -10` will save the last 10 lines of output in the pane and put them in a file called "file".